# Sequelize How compare year and month of a date

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I currently have this code:

```
Evento.findAll({
    where: db.sequelize.where(db.sequelize.fn('MONTH', db.sequelize.col('start_date')), req.body.month),
    order: ['start_date'],
    attributes: ['id', 'description', 'start_date', 'end_date', 'picture', 'status', 'place', 'text'],
    include: [{
        model: TypeEvent
    }]
}).then(events => {
    if (events) {
        res.status(200).send({
            events
        });
    } else {
        res.status(400).send({
            message: "without events"
        });
    }
});
```

but I also need to consult for the year as well and I don't know how to do it, I have tried in all the ways but I can't get the answer.

The SQL query I want :

```
SELECT .... FROM ... WHERE MONTH(start_date)=5 AND YEAR(start_date)=2021 ORDER BY ..
```

Help me please¡¡¡¡

Comment: This page explains how to use `AND` and `OR` in Sequelize: https://sequelize.org/master/manual/model-querying-basics.html#logical-combinations-with-operators

Comment: BTW, your query may run much faster if you change your query's predicate to a range-condition instead of checking for equality of components (i.e. `WHERE startDate => '2021-05-01' AND startDate < '2021-06-01'`) as this can more easily take advantage of indexes. Granted, MySQL's query engine _might_ be smart enough to do this already, but always check your `EXPLAIN`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Evento.findAll({
    where: {
        [Op.and]: [
            Sequelize.where(Sequelize.fn('MONTH', Sequelize.col('start_date')), req.body.month),
            Sequelize.where(Sequelize.fn('YEAR', Sequelize.col('start_date')), req.body.year),
        ],
    },
    order: ['start_date'],
    attributes: ['id', 'description', 'start_date', 'end_date', 'picture', 'status', 'place', 'text'],
    include: [
        {
            model: TypeEvent,
        },
    ],
}).then((events) => {
    if (events) {
        res.status(200).send({
            events,
        });
    } else {
        res.status(400).send({
            message: 'without events',
        });
    }
});
```